# SVN checkout failed

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I make a check out of my repos. After changing the directory to the newly created working one. I executed

```
svn status
```

command and I got  that there are a lot of modified files and

```
"Summary of conflicts Tree conflicts: 1".
```

How I can repair my repo to avoid such problems?

Comment: It's not about 'repairing a repo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tree Conflict is:

A tree conflict occurs when a developer moved/renamed/deleted a file or folder, which another developer either also has moved/renamed/deleted or just modified.

Try this site: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html